# How long can I keep eggs past the sell by date and still eat them?

Tags: food-safety, eggs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long can I keep  eggs in the refrigerator?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7663/how-long-can-i-keep-eggs-in-the-refrigerator)

I've got some eggs in a carton (regular Grade A eggs) in the refrigerator.  The "sell by" date on them is October 2nd.  Today is October 19th, so that's about two and a half weeks past.  Generally, foods are good for a couple weeks past the sell by date, but how many weeks do I have before they aren't edible (spoil or generally get "the funk").

If I made french toast in the morning and used them, would they be good?  I'm more concerned with 100% safety than them being 10% less awesome tasting after a certain time.