# how long can eggs sit out?

Tags: eggs

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Should I refrigerate eggs?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1672/should-i-refrigerate-eggs)
>   [How long can eggs be unrefrigerated before becoming unsafe to eat?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14775/how-long-can-eggs-be-unrefrigerated-before-becoming-unsafe-to-eat)

I got 4 dozen eggs this weekend (from actual chickens on a farm that were laid yesterday), and they sat in my car overnight.  Would they still be good to eat?  I put them in the fridge this morning.  I'd say they sat for 20 hours in my car.

Comment: And/or http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14775/how-long-can-eggs-be-unrefrigerated-before-becoming-unsafe-to-eat

Comment: how hot did it get while sitting in your car?  Eggs are ok for about 3 days, but not if they baked in your car.

Comment: You're MacGyver. Why didn't you make a refrigerator from some shoelaces, a length of pipe, duct tape, and your Swiss Army Knife?

Comment: Depends which country you live in. In general eggs are designed to be kept warm underneath the hen!

Comment: Looks like my question got 1000 views, so I earned a badge.  Answering some questions.  @Rikon - I live in Madison, WI, so in August, it's pretty hot.  I was visiting family, so the car was probably 90 degrees for at least 6 hours out of the day.  The rest of that time was near room temperature.