# Can old eggs affect my Creme Brulee?

Tags: baking, food-safety, eggs, flavor, creme-brulee

I have about a dozen eggs which are very near the expiration date and about half a dozen week or so old eggs.

Now I thought I could either  take advantage and whip up a Creme Brulee.

My question is, do old or near old eggs have any sort of positive or negative impact in the cooking process... meaning whipping, baking, serving, eating the Creme Brulee?

Please keep in mind: I have little experience in cooking.

Comment: Eggs stay fresh for a LONG time, even out on the counter. By long time I means weeks and even months if the eggs are really fresh.

Comment: I also found **[this post](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/7665/42700)** to be quite useful when it comes to thinking about eggs and their freshness

Comment: Well that discussion speaks of unwashed eggs which I have no experience with. What you buy at the stores is most certainly washed if you live in the USA. I buy eggs from the grocery store like most folks do, and the carton of eggs gets placed right on the counter. I've had them there for as long as a few weeks myself and there has never been an issue. You'll know if you get a rotten one. They turn very quickly once they start to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the eggs aren't expired you should be fine. I've made creme brulee many times with both fresh eggs and not so fresh with similar results.

Comment: Have you had any noticeable differences with fresh vs old eggs that I should be aware of? I wonder if the baking process is affected in any way because of the age of the eggs, at least for the purposes of the creme brulee. Maybe I am being a little picky but I am a bit of a perfectionist

Comment: @AGE - I'm a perfectionist as well. The main thing that could affect the outcome of your perfect creme is 1. The tempering of the cream with the egg yolks and 2. How long you leave the creme in the oven in the water bath and if you happen to splash any of the water in the creme which will be a disaster...

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, as long as the eggs are fine, it's all in the cooking of the eggs. Thanks for clearing that up