# How to interpret the date on these eggs?

Tags: eggs

My organic eggs have a date of June 24 on them; today is June 28. Can I still cook them?  (I am not used to purchasing organic eggs.)

Comment: What kind of 'date', what country & are they refrigerated? Best before, use by, sell by... there are many types.

Comment: Your question should be 'should I eat eggs past the date on the container'? Because the question you asked calls for an answer like 'I prefer mine in an omelette, with chives'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How long can I keep eggs in the refrigerator?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7663/how-long-can-i-keep-eggs-in-the-refrigerator)

Comment: Older eggs will appear watery when you break them. The flavor (as far as I can tell) is not affected. I've used egss past their date without a problem. I've also cracked plenty of 'watery' eggs which were not (supposedly) past their date. Neither made me ill.

Answer (score 4):

Check again, the date should be 'sell by' rather than 'eat by'. If you're in the US, you should have at least a couple weeks to eat them after the sell by date.

Comment: I'm puzzled by the "it must be the US if it's organic" claim. There's no monopoly on the term.

Comment: Well, Tetsujin it's not 'organic' in Europe.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod the no-ranting policy extends to all kinds of posts on the site, including comments. I edited the comments here to keep only relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

use a glass of water, if they float to the top not good, if the sink they are fresh, if they kinda float but not to the top they are ok

Comment: yes... but what do the dates mean? That was the question. Check [answer] if you'd like to learn more.