# Store cracked eggs for a week?

Tags: storage-method, eggs, storage-lifetime

I love using Egg Beaters but I want to start using more natural eggs. One of the things I love about Egg Beaters is that I can just pour the eggs from the spout, directly into my pan. Call me crazy, but I find that to be incredibly convenient for the way I cook.

So of course I can simulate this on my own by only cracking eggs once a week and putting them in a container in the fridge. But is it safe? Is there a particular container I should use? I was thinking of re-purposing something like an aluminum water bottle and just store all my eggs for the week inside that. Is that a safe practice?

Comment: Egg Beaters are not just "eggs we cracked and put in a carton." In addition to the cholesterol-free bit,  they're also pasteurized for safety.  It's unlikely that you'll have a home pasteurization setup, right?

Answer (score 3):

Fine, you're crazy. There's no time savings in shelling a lot of eggs at once .vs. shelling them as you need them, and there is a HUGE loss of storage life.

Once removed from the shell, 2-4 days is the official word, so a week - no.

http://www.foodsafety.gov/keep/charts/eggstorage.html

http://www.incredibleegg.org/cooking-school/tips-tricks/egg-storage/

The first site suggests the possibility that you might beat them and freeze them, but then fails to give a storage time for that particular option. The second site suggests that up to a year is acceptable, and further suggests adding salt or sugar to improve the texture of egg yolks that have been frozen. I have no practical experience with freezing eggs myself, they last quite long enough in the shell in my refrigerator for my purposes.

Comment: And mine are kept on the counter within reach when I am making breakfast whether cracked right into the pan for fried or beaten a little for scrambles.

Comment: @Escoce Depending on where you are, leaving them on the counter may be advisable or not; see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1672/should-i-refrigerate-eggs?lq=1

Comment: @logophobe yeah I live in the USA.